# Are these boundary conditions consistent $y(x,0)=\cos(\pi x)$ and $y(0,t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I was asked to solve
$$\dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}=9\dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}$$
with the boundary conditions
$y(x,0)=\cos(\pi x)$,$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}(x,0)$ and $y(0,t)=y(4,t)=0$

Aren't these boundary conditions inconsistent
since if $y(0,t)=0$ (for all $t$) this would imply $y(0,0)=0$
on the other hand $y(x,0)=\cos(\pi x)$ (for all $x$) this would imply that $y(0,0)=1$
Am I wrond somewhere or are these boundary condtions indeed inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These boundary conditions do not inconsistent despite the fact that the conditions of agreement in the corner are not met. This implies that your problem does not have a classic solution. Moreover it does not have continuous solution. Your solution will not have a generalized derivative everywhere (but will have derivative almost everywhere), since there will be a discontinuity of the first kind.

You can solve this problem using separation of variables (in Hilbert space), and solution will be represented as trigonometric series, which will correspond to a distribution. The derivatives of these series may not converge. But on some domains Cesàro summation can give meaning to these series. Nevertheless, on some characteristics, the Cesàro summation will not help, because there the dirac delta will appear.

Edit 1. Building a solution.

Separation of variables: $u(x, t) = X(x)T(t)$.

1. $X''(x) + \lambda X(x) = 0$, $X(0) = X(4) = 0$.
2. $T''(t) +9\lambda T(t) = 0$.

From 1) we get $X_n(x) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{4}\right)$, $\lambda_n = (\frac{\pi n}{4})^2$.
From 2) we get $T_n(t) = A_n \cos\left(\frac{3 \pi n t}{4}\right) + B_n\sin \left(\frac{3 \pi n t}{4}\right)$.

So, $u(x, t) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(A_n \cos\left(\frac{3 \pi n t}{4}\right) + B_n\sin\left( \frac{3 \pi n t}{4}\right)\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{4}\right)$.

Using initial condition we obtain $A_n=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^4 \cos (\pi x) \sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{4}\right) dx$ and $B_n=0$.
We can calculate integral and get $A_n = -\frac{2 \left((-1)^n-1\right) n}{\pi 
   \left(n^2-16\right)}$ for $n\neq 4$, and $A_4 = 0$.
We notice, that $A_{2m} = 0$ and $A_{2 m + 1} = \frac{8 m+4}{\pi  \left(4 m^2+4
   m-15\right)}$.

So, we have built the solution as trigonomical series $u(x, t)=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{8 m+4}{\pi  \left(4 m^2+4
   m-15\right)} \cos\left(\frac{3 \pi t (2 m + 1)}{4}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi x (2 m + 1)}{4}\right)$.